# Zero divisors and the Peano Axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, peano-axioms

Using the Peano axioms, how can it be proven that the only zero divisor of the natural numbers is $0$ (or there is no zero divisor depending on your definition).

Can it even be done? Do new axioms need to be introduced?

Namely, how can the Peano axioms be using to prove that $ab = 0 \implies a = 0 \lor b = 0$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not difficult to show by induction using the Peano axioms that $mn = 0$ implies one of $m$ or $n$ is $0$.

Comment: @Troposphere: I think it depends on exactly what formulation of PA you use. If you use the one discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms, then you need induction to prove $\forall m (m = 0 \lor (\exists n(m = S(n)))$.

Comment: @Troposphere: it's my bedtime. I agree it's a simple (but necessary) lemma. Now we are on the same wavelength, why don't you write up an answer?

Comment: @RobArthan: Comments moved to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where we can (almost!) prove an interesting general fact in Peano Arithmetic *without* using induction.

The recursion equations that define $+$ and $\times$ immediately unfold to
$$ \forall x,y: S(x)\times S(y) = S(S(x)\times y + x)$$
and since another axiom says that $0$ is not a successor this gives
$$ \forall x,y: S(x) \times S(y) \ne 0 $$

To get from here to $m\times n = 0 \to m=0 \lor n=0$ you just need the fact that everything is either zero or a successor. That final fact does require induction. (But this induction is literally the first application of the induction axiom in every development of Peano arithmetic I remember reading.)

Comment: Minor caveat: if you distinguish between first-order "Peano _Arithmetic_" and the second-order "Peano _axioms_", and you specifically want the latter system, then not even $S(x)\times S(y)\ne 0$ is really reached "without induction". In that system, addition and multiplication are not primitive notions, and you need induction to show their definitions by recursion equations make sense, before you can start asking about zero divisors at all.